# livecd-iso-to-disk fail

Tags: boot, usb-device

I use `livecd-iso-to-disk` to make multiple boot usb disk. But get the error, of course I had added `--reset-mbr`.

```
▶ sudo livecd-iso-to-disk --format --reset-mbr --efi --multi --livedir fedora '/home/eexpss/ISO/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3.iso' /dev/sdc1
Verifying image...
/home/eexpss/ISO/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3.iso:   ec5039af1735642e222e97e02ab0e1e9
Fragment sums: f48e661d962e6316cbc6e16a4ee4ff9f99fa06151ceacc4f3f1973368a93
Fragment count: 20
Supported ISO: no
Press [Esc] to abort check.
Checking: 100.0%

The media check is complete, the result is: PASS.

It is OK to use this media.
/bin/livecd-iso-to-disk: line 492: : command not found

    WARNING: This will DESTROY All DATA on: /dev/sdc !!

        Press Enter to continue, or Ctrl C to abort.

/dev/sdc: 8 bytes were erased at offset 0x00000200 (gpt): 45 46 49 20 50 41 52 54
/dev/sdc: 8 bytes were erased at offset 0x1cdd7ee00 (gpt): 45 46 49 20 50 41 52 54
/dev/sdc: 2 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001fe (PMBR): 55 aa
/dev/sdc: calling ioctl to re-read partition table: Success
Waiting for devices to settle...
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)

        ALERT:
        The partition name must be 'EFI System Partition'.

        This can be set with a partition editor, such as parted,
        or you can run livecd-iso-to-disk with the --reset-mbr option.
```

Here is line 488 to 499 in `/bin/livecd-iso-to-disk`.

```
checkLVM() {
    local dev=$1

    if type pvs >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
        "$(pvs -o vg_name --noheadings $dev* 2>/dev/null || :)"; then  <-- line 492
        printf "\n        ATTENTION:
        Device '$dev' contains a volume group and cannot be formatted!\n\n
        You can remove the volume group using vgremove.\n"
        exitclean
    fi
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After test dozen times, I found it comes from **--efi**. When I get rid of this parameter, I can continue to execute.

I think maybe livecd-iso-to-disk had not well support on LVM and UEFI.